# How does " ~ " find complements in C?

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators

I am asking this question because I found in Stack Overflow an example of finding the difference without using minus (' - ')operator.

The answer was given by difference= a+ ~b +1;

Why +1 ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_NOT_.22.7E.22_.2F_One.27s_Complement_.28Unary.29

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: Whatever book you're using to learn C, you need to find a better one. Any decent book on C will explain what the `~` operator is.

Comment: Upvoters do you really feel _"This question shows research efforts; it is useful and clear"_ ?

Comment: @P0W i asked the question because i did not know the answer. Sorry if You seem to feel the question is a mistake. Please do give answer if you cant let others do. I dont look the votes. thanks

Comment: @MELWIN If you don't know the answer, you probably need a good C book, concentrate in class, SO is neither a private tutor, nor its a discussion forum, instead of posting this you could shown some research effort, programming is learnt by practice and lots of errort. I'm no C expert, its just a free advice, helpful for future.

Comment: Asking a question on SO itself is a research effort. No need to downvote the question. Sometimes people just may not be able to find results.

Comment: @P0W and(RaymondChen Maxime Cogwheel BЈовић) You all are experts in C. I am only a beginner. I think you all have started from where I also started. You all have all put the question on "HOLD". You could also have told something that may be useful to answer my doubt. Anyway I have got answer. And I am really satisfied.

"Do help the Questioner rather than just suppressing them". a simple and humble advice totally free to all of you as it should help you in future to help beginners.

Comment: @MELWIN you should do the effort of searching by yourself before asking for help. The meaning of ~ can be found in any book about C programming. Type "unary operator" in Google and click on the first or second link. You can also try "tilde C" and you'll find a stack overflow question. Stack Overflow rule states that the OP must shows research efforts. You did not.

Comment: @AliAlamiri Asking a question on SO does not satisfy the SO requirement for *prior* research.

Comment: @EJP If your prior research did not help you much for some reason, then there is no issue in asking on SO. I don't know why people make such big deals of these type of questions. The question is clear and can be useful for someone who may search for the same question in the future and will be able to find this question and its answer.

Comment: Acting entitled and condescending to industry experts certainly won't get you very far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In c, it is a bit-wise NOT operator. Read: [Operators in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B).

```
a + ~b + 1;
```

is the "2's complement"<sub>1</sub> method for subtracting. To subtract `2` from `3` computer can use this [2's complement method](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~csonline/NumberSystems/Lessons/SubtractionWithTwosComplement/index.html). Suppose you are on `8` bit architecture, then: (3)<sub>10</sub> = (0000 0011)<sub>2</sub>  and (2)<sub>10</sub> = (0000 0010)<sub>2</sub>.
Now taking complement (NOT) of `2`,

```
~(0000 0010) = 1111 1101
```

Now taking its 2's complement (just add 1 to it)

```
 1111 1101 + 1 = 1111 1110
```

Now adding the 2's complement of `2` to `3`;

```
  0000 0011 
+ 1111 1110 
------------
1 0000 0001  = 1 in decimal. (3 - 2 = 1)
^
|
Carry Bit
```

---

<sub>1. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) says:</sub>

> <sub>The two's complement of a number behaves like the negative of the original number in most arithmetic, and positive and negative numbers can coexist in a natural way.</sub>

Comment: You could also explain why `a+ ~b +1` is equivalent to `a - b`.

Comment: @Maxime; Oh! Yes. Editing it now.

Comment: Also, for reference, it is important to mention that this assumes twos complement representation, thus it is not entirely portable (though twos complement is used in nearly every C implementation)

Comment: Or, you could simply state:  _In c, it is a bit-wise NOT operator._ , and leave a link to explain it further, just as you did.  Your original answer was sufficient the way it was (for crying out loud.)

Comment: @haccks thank you for the explanation :) I am satisfied.

one more doubt. if b= 2 what will be displayed if we print ~b ???

Comment: :) @haccks I did try.
b=2;
printf("%d",~b);
output was -3 .

now one more doubt :
(is there any direct method to display 1111 1101 ?)

Comment: That's a _question_, not a "doubt"